How can I use a terminal emulator as an efficient application launcher?
The Problem
I've used various application launchers like rofi, albert, wofi, dmenu, and others throughout my Linux years. While they have their pros and cons, one thing has always bothered me: they're not a bash shell.
Why does this matter? I really enjoy some of the bash's features, such as:

GNU Readline shortcuts: Navigating or edit text with Ctrl+A (beginning of line), Ctrl+E (end), Ctrl+K (kill text), Ctrl+Y (yank), Meta+Y (yank history), and more.
Command history: Using ~/.bash_history for searching with Ctrl+R/Ctrl+S, or navigating commands with Ctrl+P/Ctrl+N.
Tab completion: With tools like bash-completion and bash-complete-alias, I have powerful auto-completion for paths, command names, and arguments.
Aliases: Some programs are easier and faster to launch via my custom aliases.


My Goal
I want to use a terminal emulator as a simple application launcher. Here’s how it should work:

Press a shortcut key to launch the terminal (e.g., kitty).
Type a command (e.g., firefox).
Press <Enter>. The terminal should:

Launch the command.
Immediately close itself.
Leave the launched application running.



For example, typing firefox should behave like executing firefox & disown & exit or nohup firefox > /dev/null 2>&1 & exit. Typing & disown & exit after the command achieves the desired effect, but, of course, I don't want to manually add & disown & exit every time.
Note: this is not window swallowing. I don’t want the terminal window to linger after the application closes; I only need it for input.

What I’ve Tried

Using read:
Launching kitty with this command:
kitty -e bash -i -c 'read -e -p "Command: " cmd; eval "$cmd"'

This approach fails because typing via read bypasses some of the shell features I want, like tab completion and command history.

Automating with a secondary shortcut:
Typing the command and using another shortcut (e.g., Super+<Enter>) to append and execute & disown & exit<Enter> with a tool like wtype.
This is very workaroundish, but I'd settle for it, if it worked. Unfortunately, it does not: pressing a modifier key like Super causes unwanted behavior: every character in the string (& disown & exit<Enter>) is sent with the modifier, triggering shortcuts instead of being interpreted as text.



Conclusion
How can I achieve this? I want a solution that lets me quickly launch applications while leveraging all the features of an interactive bash shell.

I'd go about it in this mental order:

Modify your shell to "hook" the execution of commands
in that hook, you don't execute the command itself, but

spawn the program in the context of your graphical shell (so, no disowning or nohuping`
exit your shell (thus closing the window).



The installation of that hook could be done in a custom RC file that you specify to load.
The hook itself:
easy  on zsh
(I'd actually recommend zsh here), just implement preexec; put something like the following in your  ~/.zshrc
preexec() {
  # /--------------------+--- unless we're in "only a glorified command prompt mode", skip
  # |                    |
  # |                    |
  # |                    |    /-- run using "systemd-run" in user contex
  # |                    |    |                   /--- stay in same working directory
  # |                    |    |                   |    
  # |                    |    |                   |    
  # |                    |    |                   |   /-- ${=VARIABLE} expands a variable
  # |                    |    |                   |   |   containing spaces into a list of
  # |                    |    |                   |   |   separate arguments
  # |                    |    |                   |   |
  # |                    |    |                   |   |       /-- if all went well, quit!
  # |                    |    |                   |   |       |
  # vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv    v                   v   v       v
  [[ -v PROMPT_AND_EXIT ]] && systemd-run --user -d ${=2} && exit
  #                                                    ^
  #                                                    |
  #  `preexec()` gets three arguments: 1. is the string as typed by user, 2. is "pre-expanded",
  #  and 3. argument is the fully expanded string (after aliases and functions).
  #  That third argument, $2, is what we use.
}

and run your terminal like kitty -e env PROMPT_AND_EXIT=1 zsh.
bash: possible, but a bit harder, I think
haven't really tried it, but I'm sure you can "cobble" together a similar behaviour on bash as you get with preexec on zsh. A quick skim of bash's source code doesn't show anything that resembles zsh's preexec(), but you can probably implement a DEBUG something_invoke_exec hook. That sounds like a fair bit more work (and potentially has performance downsides), but it would allow you to do conceptually the same as I've showed for zsh. Haven't tried that, though, for limited time (and limited use – I find bash's command line editing much less advanced than zsh's, and hence prefer the latter in interactive use). Would be worth for you to investigate!
